# How do you identify an existing record (using the QuickBooks API) without a ListID?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

The QuickBooks Desktop SDK, had a ListID on each record. However, the QuickBooks API returns an ID field.

Without a shared id, how can you match records from the QuickBooks API with those from the SDK?

Comment: There's no "official" way to do this, but the above thread has a possible solution.